# easyautocomplete jquery show list onfocus

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, focus

I want to use easyautocomplete script (http://easyautocomplete.com) but I want show all list after onFocus event not after keyDown.
Is anybody can help me?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input").easyAutocomplete(options).click(function(){ 
    $(this).triggerHandler(jQuery.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 65, which: 65})) 
});
```

this works for me

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const $input = $("#search-input")
let e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
e.which = 8; //choose the one you want
e.keyCode = 8;
$input.val(" ").trigger(e);
let val = $input.val();
if (val == " ") $input.val(val.replace(" ", ""));
```